What's the best way for a system service to start a user session?
I've got an Ubuntu 18+ system service written in Python.  Once it authenticates a user, it starts a tigervncserver listening on UNIX sockets for both its X and VNC connections, then proxies traffic to the VNC connection.  It's a websocket-to-TCP proxy, so the service can't step out of the picture completely, as it has work to do.
I want the tigervncserver script and everything it spawns off (an X server with an entire GNOME session) to go into its own systemd session.
Right now, I'm doing it basically like this:
args = ['sudo', 'machinectl', 'shell', UNIXuser+'@.host',
        '/usr/bin/tigervncserver',
        '-localhost', 'yes',
        '-SendPrimary=0', '-SetPrimary=0',
        '-rfbunixpath', rfbpath,
        '-SecurityTypes', 'None',
        '-BlacklistThreshold', '1000000',
        '-fg',
]

subprocess.Popen(args, start_new_session=True)

This works, but this leaves both the tigervncserver and the sudo running until the session ends.  If I take the -fg switch off, so the tigervncserver script exits, leaving the server running in the background, the session appears briefly on loginctl, then vanishes with its processes killed.
I've tried systemd-run but can't get its --machine switch to accept something like USERNAME@.host.  It behaves like this:
$ sudo systemd-run --machine BrentBaccala@.host /bin/bash
Failed to create bus connection: Invalid argument

I've tried other variants of systemd-run with the --uid switch instead of --machine, with no luck.
Can somebody suggest a better way to have a system service start a new user session running a VNC server?  In particular, I'd like to let the script and the sudo exit, leaving the vnc server running in background.
